# Force nodes created by Feeds module to be published even if nodes are unpublished by default

Tags: 6, nodes, feeds

How can I do this? Force nodes created by Feeds module to be published even if regular nodes are unpublished by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) for the 'presave' operation to set the node status to published if there is a new one created by Feeds:

```
function MODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op === 'presave' && empty($node->nid) && !empty($node->feeds_node_item)) {
    $node->status = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this

Answer (score 2):

Making nodes published is not a problem, the question is how are we going to tell the nodes created by Feeds. The quickest options are

1. a separate node type for imported content, or
2. a hidden field that only gets set via Feeds mapping

Assuming none of the quick solutions would fit your scenario, the only actual way to tell Feed-created nodes is the `feeds_node_item`. After importing a node, it will contain a record for the node, with `nid` column set to the node id.

Making use of the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, the whole trick is just a matter of an *Execute custom PHP code* for condition to check if the record is there for the newly created node:

*Add new rule*

**Event:** After saving new content

*Add a condition*

**Select the condition to add:** Execute custom PHP code

*PHP code*

```
<?php
$a = db_fetch_array(db_query("select count(*) c from {feeds_node_item}
                              where nid = %d", array($node->nid)));
return $a['c'] != 0;
?>
```

*Add an action*

**Select an action to add:** Publish content

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to expose the user status as a mapper; see the patch proposed in [Add user status to FeedsUserProcessor](http://drupal.org/node/1228568), which would be similar.